# Python @ (at) prefix in top level module code - What does it stand for?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I thought it would be a good idea to as this question here since google outright ignores the `@` character in a query.

What does the `@` before an earlier declared function name do when used in the top level of a document, multiple times, just before `def`´s?

[Example](https://github.com/jwandborg/minecraft-overviewer/blob/master/nbt.py#L28)

As a follow up, is it still present in Python 3?

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_syntax_and_semantics#Decorators