# Python documentation for @?

Tags: python

Just a quick question,

Could someone link me to the documentation for the use of @ in python?

Due not being able to google @ and not knowing the use or name of it I'm not sure how to find it on my own :)

Many thanks!!

Comment: Very similar question to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5337890/python-at-prefix-in-top-level-module-code-what-does-it-stand-for/5337982#5337982

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Symbols starting with "@" (e.g. @staticmethod) are called "decorators" in Python jargon.

You can find the PEP describing them [at this url](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0318/).

In short, they are syntactic sugar to invoke a function over the object being decorated, e.g.:

```
@staticmethod
def myfunc(...): ...
```

is equivalent to:

```
def myfunc(...): ...
myfunc = staticmethod(myfunc)
```

Then, searching on the web for "python decorator" will provide you with a lot of other useful information and use cases.

Hope it helps, ciao

Comment: Also in the python docs [glossary page](http://docs.python.org/glossary.html#term-decorator) and discussed under [function definitions](http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#function)

Answer (score 4):

Python decorators:

http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#function

Answer (score 2):

Google for `python decorator` and you will find enough answers to your question.

Answer (score 0):

As other people said, they are decorators. They take the decorated object as an argument and return a new object - which should usually be the same type as the initial one (function or class)

If you do not like the at syntax, you can always write it like that:

```
@foo
def bar():
    pass

# is the same as:
def bar():
    pass
bar = foo(bar)
```